# not able to get the selected option from select options or dropdown in webdriverIO

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

To get the selected option from a dropdown or select element, I am using below code block, but the selectedText once out of for loop returns blank, but it should return the value assigned in if condition. can anyone assist?

```html
it('verify select dropdown...', async () => {
        browser.url("https://qavbox.github.io/demo/signup/")
        await browser.pause(2000)
        let select = await $("select[name='sgender']")
        let options = await select.$$('option')
        console.log("options count - " + options.length)

        let selectedText = ""
        options.filter(async option => {
            if (await option.isSelected()) {
              selectedText = await option.getText()
              console.log("inside loop - selectedText is: " + selectedText)
              return
            }
        })
        console.log("outside loop - selectedText is: " + selectedText)
        await browser.pause(2000)
    });
```

console.log("inside loop - selectedText is: " + selectedText)
output - Select:

console.log("outside loop - selectedText is: " + selectedText)
Output -

but I am expecting the output of outside loop as "Select:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be because of how `Array.filter` or `Array.forEach` are dealt with asynchronously in nodejs. If you have noticed the console, `outside loop` is logged before the `inside loop`.

```
[0-0] options count - 4
[0-0] outside loop - selectedText is: 
[0-0] inside loop - selectedText is: Select:
```

This can be fixed by traditional for looping over the array.

```
it('verify select dropdown...', async () => {
    browser.url('https://qavbox.github.io/demo/signup/');
    await browser.pause(2000);
    let select = await $("select[name='sgender']");
    await select.selectByIndex(1);
    let options = await select.$$('option');
    console.log('options count - ' + options.length);

    let selectedText;
    for (let index = 0; index < options.length; index++) {
      console.log('Before the loop: ' + index + ' ' + selectedText);
      if (await options[index].isSelected()) {
        selectedText = await options[index].getText();
        console.log('inside loop - selectedText is: ' + selectedText);
      }
    }
    console.log('outside loop - selectedText is: ' + selectedText);
    await browser.pause(2000);
  });
```

Outputs:

```
[0-0] options count - 4
[0-0] Before the loop: 0 undefined
[0-0] Before the loop: 1 undefined
[0-0] inside loop - selectedText is: Male
[0-0] Before the loop: 2 Male
[0-0] Before the loop: 3 Male
[0-0] outside loop - selectedText is: Male
```

Comment: isSelected also looks for the selected option from the dropdown irrespective of selected attribute is present or not, that's why my insideloop "selectedText" variable has the value "Select:"
But the outside forloop, the same variable "selectedText" loses it's value assigned, that's the issue!

Comment: @sunpat Seems so. I have updated my answer.